# Dojo build requesting already inlined templates

Tags: templates, build, dojo, google-closure-compiler

I'm hopelessly trying to make the `Dijit template` inlining functionality of `Dojo builds` for my AMD project work with no luck yet ...

The particular issue isn't the inlining of the HTML templates themselves, but the fact that they are still requested with Ajax (XHR) after being successfully inlined.

Templates are inlined the following way :

```
"url:app/widgets/Example/templates/example.html": '<div>\n\tHello World!</div>'
```

The Dijit widget itself, after building, defines templates like this :

```
define("dojo/_base/declare,dijit/_Widget,dojo/text!./templates/example.html".split(","), function (f, g, d) {
    return f("MyApp.Example", [g], {
        templateString: d,
    });
});
```

I tried to build with :

- the shrinksafe / closure optimiser
- relative / absolute paths
- using the old `cache()` method
- using the `templatePath` property

but even after having run a successful build (0 errrors and a few warnings) where the templates were inlined, Dojo / Dijit still makes Ajax requests to these resources.

Here is my build profile :

```
var profile = {
    basePath: '../src/',
    action: 'release',
    cssOptimize: 'comments',
    mini: true,
    optimize: 'closure',
    layerOptimize: 'closure',
    stripConsole: 'all',
    selectorEngine: 'acme',
    internStrings: true,
    internStringsSkipList: false,
    packages: [
        'dojo',
        'dijit',
        'dojox',
        'app'
    ],
    layers: {
        'dojo/dojo': {
            include: [
                'app/run'
            ],
            boot: true,
            customBase: true
        },
    },
    staticHasFeatures: {
        'dojo-trace-api': 0,
        'dojo-log-api': 0,
        'dojo-publish-privates': 0,
        'dojo-sync-loader': 0,
        'dojo-xhr-factory': 0,
        'dojo-test-sniff': 0
    }
};
```

Due to this issue my application is completely unusable because there are so many files to download separately (browsers have a limit on the number of parallel connections).

Thank you very much in advance !

UPDATE :

The two lines loading dojo.js and the run.js in my `index.html` :

```
<script data-dojo-config='async: 1, tlmSiblingOfDojo: 0, isDebug: 1' src='/public/dojo/dojo.js'></script>
<script src='/public/app-desktop/run.js'></script>
```

Here is the new `build-profile` :

```
var profile = {
    basePath: '../src/',
    action: 'release',
    cssOptimize: 'comments',
    mini: true,
    internStrings: true,
    optimize: 'closure',
    layerOptimize: 'closure',
    stripConsole: 'all',
    selectorEngine: 'acme',
    packages        : [
        'dojo',
        'dijit',
        'app-desktop'
    ],
    layers: {
        'dojo/dojo': {
            include: [
                'dojo/request/xhr',
                'dojo/i18n',
                'dojo/domReady',
                'app-desktop/main'
            ],
            boot: true,
            customBase: true
        }
    },
    staticHasFeatures: {
        'dojo-trace-api': 0,
        'dojo-log-api': 0,
        'dojo-publish-privates': 0,
        'dojo-sync-loader': 0,
        'dojo-xhr-factory': 0,
        'dojo-test-sniff': 0
    }
};
```

My new `run.js` file :

```
require({
    async: 1,
    isDebug: 1,
    baseUrl: '/public',
    packages: [
        'dojo',
        'dijit',
        'dojox',
        'saga',
        'historyjs',
        'wysihtml5',
        'app-shared',
        'jquery',
        'jcrop',
        'introjs',
        'app-desktop'
    ],
    deps: [
        'app-desktop/main',
        'dojo/domReady!'
    ],
    callback: function (Main) {
        debugger;
        var main = new Main();
        debugger;
        main.init();
    }
});
```

and my `main.js` file looks like this :

```
define([
    'dojo/_base/declare',
    'app-desktop/widgets/Application',
    'app-desktop/config/Config',
    'saga/utils/Prototyping',
    'dojo/window',
    'dojo/domReady!'
], function (declare, Application, ConfigClass, Prototyping, win) {

    return declare([], {
        init: function() {

            // ... other stuff

            application = new Application();
            application.placeAt(document.body);

            // ... some more stuff
        }
    });

});
```

In `build-mode`, I get the following error :

```
GET http://localhost:4000/app-desktop/run.js 404 (Not Found)
```

which is weird because it means that the build process made it so that dojo has an external dependency rather than an a already inlined `dojoConfig` variable in the builded file.

In `normal-mode`, files get requested, but the app is never created.

In both cases none of the two debuggers set in the run.js file were run which means that the `callback` method was never called for some reason.

Thank you for your help !

Comment: What happens if you **don't** use the `"A,B,C".split(",")` trick inside your widget? (In other words, just `["A","B","C"]` ) Perhaps there's some parsing/regex magic going on and that breaks it?

Comment: I tried replacing the string + split hack into a conventional array, but sadly, this didn't work.

Comment: Closure-compiler expands "A,B,C".split(",") expressions into a standard array during compilation. It makes code easier to optimize.

Comment: Yeah, I thought it would be like this but even when using shrinksafe in place of the Closure-compiler, which means that dependencies are defined in standard array you get the same bug.

Comment: i see ""url:app/widgets/..." and in your packages you list 'app-desktop' - i wonder if that has anything to do with this.  also, after searching the builder code, internStringsSkipList seems to do nothing so you can leave that out and internStrings is true by default so that can be left out too.

Comment: Sorry, this is only a mistake in my example rather than a bug. But thank you for default I can remove from my build profile !

Comment: ok, i dug a bit deeper again... are you declaring your packages in your dojoConfig for your built app?  the "url:app/widgets/..." key should work with dojo/text as long as the proper config is in place to convert that to the right url.

Comment: @m_vdbeek i created an example repo at https://github.com/neonstalwart/inlined-build - could you modify it so that it produces the issue you're seeing and then open a Pull Request with the modifications so i can diagnose the issue?

Comment: deps and callback don't work in a call to require - they only work in dojoConfig.  the only thing that surprises me by what you've said is that app-desktop/run.js is not found.  you don't include it in your dojo.js layer so i don't know how that url is even being loaded unless you have another module that depends on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've printed values of `requireCacheUrl` and `require.cache` to console in the method load() of dojo/text.js. At least in my case, keys of my templates in the cache differs from lookup keys on one leading slash.

For example, I have `"dojo/text!./templates/Address.html"` in my widget. It present with key `url:/app/view/templates/Address.html` in the cache but is searched like `url:app/view/templates/Address.html`, causing cache miss and xhr request.

With additional slash in dojo/text.js (line 183 for version 1.9.1) it seemingly works (line would looks like `requireCacheUrl = "url:/" + url`).

Not sure what kind of bugs this "fix" could introduce. So, it probably worth to report this issue to dojo folks.

UPD: Well, I see you've already reported this issue. Here is the link: https://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/ticket/17458.

UPD: Don't use hack described above. It was only attempt to narrow issue. Real issue in my project was with packages and baseUrl settings. Initially I created my project based on https://github.com/csnover/dojo-boilerplate. Then fixed it as in [neonstalwart's sample](https://github.com/neonstalwart/inlined-build).

Comment: Ok, I did some tests with and templates nothing seems to inline anymore, should it be JavaScript files or HTML files (1.8.3 and 1.9.1). BUT I tried to replace URLs by random strings and it worked ! So it is definitely related to the URL construction !

Comment: Well, this trick definetly works for me. Just to clarify: I replaced string 183 in my local copy of dojo/text.js. I use full source release 1.9.1. Line was "requireCacheUrl = "url:" + url," and my current version is "requireCacheUrl = (url.charAt(0) == '/' ? 'url:' : 'url:/') + url,". There could be some scenarios, that this fix brakes, I admit. My project is small yet, and don't cover many scenarios, but I don't see any issues right now. If you try to reproduce this, be sure that build tool uses fixed dojo library file.

Comment: Also, I started with https://github.com/csnover/dojo-boilerplate, had to add 'app/run' to includes of layer in app.profile, so that this file also packed into dojo.js, then had to fix baseUrl in dojoConfig. Not sure, but may be these things also related to produce templete's url. Here is how I setup baseUrl: var dojoConfig = (function () {
        var base = location.pathname.split('/');
        base.pop();
        base = base.join('/');
        return {baseUrl: base, isDebug: 1, async: 1};
    })();

Comment: With these fixes all scripts goes in only one file and there are only several additional requests for css, png and so on.

If you use Chrome, unmark option "Enable source maps" in the settings of development console, as it downloads debug versions of sources when console is opened with this option.

Comment: I've done some test where the templates didn't seem to get requested so that worked, on the other hand, Dojo's files were not found inside the source anymore. Any ideas ?

Comment: Handful of things can go wrong. Basically one need to ensure that every widget or other dojo module required via app/run. I provided a link for boilerplate that I started from. In its build script there is somewhat brittle regexp replacement that replaces <script src="app/run.js"></script> with dep['app/run'] in dojoConfig. If one use it, he should ensure, that script tag matches exactly. It is main entry point for module dependencies for runtime. File app.file is an entry point for build. I included 'dojo/i18n', 'dojo/domReady', 'app' and 'app/run' in app.profile.

Comment: Next, here is my run.js:

`require({
    baseUrl: '',
    packages: [
        'dojo',
        'dijit',
        'dojox',

        { name: 'app', location: 'app', map: {} }
    ]

}, [ 'app/main', 'dojo/domReady!' ], function(main) {
    main.init();
});`

It requires app/main.js and invokes its method init(). In my main.js there is a define() which requires every widget module, used on the index.html both standard and custom. Module defines init function, where I manually invoke parser.parse(). Modules required in main.js than require other modules and so on.

Comment: Notice baseUrl in dojoConfig and run.js, they a bit different and works together. Unfortunately, can't remember|find where I borrowed this combination of options.

Comment: @nikolay_turpitko are you able to try https://github.com/neonstalwart/inlined-build and change it to reproduce the issue you're seeing?  i tried to intentionally break the code to find the problems you're both seeing but i'm unable to make it break.  maybe i know the "rules" so well that i don't know how to break them :)  fwiw, i don't think adding the '/' like you've done is going to be the final solution here.

Comment: Hey @neonstalwart I tried to copy the config you have in the "inlined-build repo", but I keep getting the error that there is the 'app/run' file missing. Any ideas ?

Comment: @neonstalwart, in "non-build-mode" everything works fine, but after building successfully by adding a run file that copies exactly what you have inlined in the `index.html` file for the require config, I get an `Unexpected token ILLEGAL` error on my index.html file.

Comment: Ok, so it seems that the callback in the dojoConfig I inserted in my run.js file is never called for some reason.

Comment: @neonstalwart Ok, I've reproduced issue with your code without changing a char. Just try to host it on local server at URL like this: http://localhost:8585/zzz/index.html, then load it in browser and you'll see in debug console that it requests App.html. Notice "zzz" part in the URL. Tried in Chrome and Opera - the same. Cannot test in firefox, as it crashes in Ubuntu from last week.

Comment: @nikolay_turpitko : Yes, I saw the same thing happening in my builds. By changing the path in the `url:path/example.html` by some random string and replacing every occurrence it worked.

Comment: @neonstalwart : I updated my answer with and appended at the end the new `main.js`, `run.js`, dojo loader in the `index.html` and `build profile`. At the end, I also wrote what these files gave as a result. Should it be with or without building. Thanks for your help !

Comment: @neonstalwart I've debugged dojo/text with dojoConfig = { baseUrl: '.' } and without baseUrl in app/run.js. In this scenario dojo/text searches for `url:app/view/templates/When.html` but value sits in cache with the key `url:../app/view/templates/When.html`. I agree, that hack I used will only work with particular baseUrl settings and project layout. But it allows to quick and dirty fix issue, providing that you host your own copy of dojo lib with your own project. And this is the case when you build your sources into one file with lib.

Comment: i'm not sure what is causing the problem for you guys.  i've checked out my repository exactly as it is, run build.sh, and served it from a URL with path of /inlined-build/release and i see no extra files being requested.  https://saucelabs.com/tests/fb95f63d7d494dc6ba56d3fa9006e8f8 has a video of the session.  if you can make a pull request with failing code or give some really clear instructions i can look into it some more for you.

Comment: @neonstalwart I've freshly cloned your sample and couldn't reproduce issue again. So, following your sample, I've removed app/run.js from my project completely, moved packages settings from it to profile and dojoConfig, added deps and callback to dojoConfig and removed related "magic" from build.sh. Issue certainly gone. Thanks! How can I pass my reward for this answer to you?

Comment: @neonstalwart Unfortunately, I cannot afford more time for further experiments. Would you try to reproduce issue with this project: https://github.com/csnover/dojo-boilerplate (host it in some subfolder on local server)? It would be generous to fix it, because there are links to it from Dojo site.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like https://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/ticket/17141. If it is, you just need to update to Dojo 1.9.1.

Comment: This didn't work. I checked-out on the 1.9.1 tag on the Dojo, Dijit, Dojox and Util repo but this didn't change anything.

Comment: By inspecting the minimised source-code, there was one difference. Now the templates are all inlined at the end of the file rather than being scattered everywhere in the file but that's it.

Comment: What browser(s) are you using to test?

Comment: Google Chrome 29 mostly.